# Best practices for setting up Linux "service" user

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu, user-management

I've set up a server running Ubuntu to host a backend based on Node and MongoDB with Nginx as reverse proxy. When I first logged into the machine I was root, and without thinking too much that's the account I used for setting everything up. Beginners mistake I guess. Going into production running everything as root seems like a bad idea, but I can't find any good articles describing how to set up an account and making sure it starts the services I need after reboot, what access the account will need etc. Any tips?

Comment: How come you did this at root in the first place? The default installation of Ubuntu has root disabled and creates a user that has sudo-privileges. This is already a very good configuration. The installation of Node, MongoDB and and NginX (via apt) creates service users and systemd services for automatic start of the services. There should be nothing left to do.

Comment: It's a Digital Ocean Droplet, and when you access it through their web console after creation I believe you are root by default. I know it wasn't the right thing to do and that's why I want to set things right now.